# How extend linux partition with?(after success to extend : fail to boot computer)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, hard-disk

I have Ubuntu and I want to enlarge the disk space of /dev/sda1 from 10GB to 90GB.

gparted Ubuntu 9.04 live cd show:

```
 Partition    File System   Size
 /dev/sda1    ext4          10GB
 /dev/sda2    linux-swap    4GB
 unallocated  unallocated   146000
```

I would like to get this disk map:

```
 Partition    File System   Size
 /dev/sda1    ext4          90GB
 /dev/sda2    linux-swap    4GB
 unallocated  unallocated   56000
```

I click on /dev/sda1 and option resize only gives the option to reduce and not enlarge disk.

If gparted cannot handle this, are there other tools that would?

(I think that I should merge /dev/sda1 with unallocated but I don't know how to do it.)

---

**Update:failing boot** - unable to enter to my ubuntu OS, infinite loop in begining(solve the problem to enlarge partition but blocked to enter to my partition OS):

What I done:

1. delete  /dev/sda2
2. resize /dev/sda1 to 160GB
3. create  /dev/sda2  with size 4GB primary partition and make it linux-swap
4. restart PC and remove ubuntu live cd - result: unable to access to my installed before ubuntu OS.

my current map according gparted ubuntu live cd:

```
 Partition    File System   Size
 /dev/sda1    ext4          156GB
 /dev/sda2    linux-swap    4GB
```

**Update2:**

reinstall bootloader(Mat idea - thank you very much)
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2
Thanks,

Comment: Is there any error message when it fails to boot Ubuntu? How old is your BIOS? Error messages would help. Maybe you're hitting some disk addressing limitation. (If that's the case, the solution would involve moving the bootloader files to a separate partition, to be mounted as `/boot` in the running system -- this partition would have to be at the beginning of the disk, and carry the bootloader files (if you're using a bootloader that has external files, such as `GNU GRUB`) and the kernel images (and initrds, if you're using that too))

Comment: no error, just not getting to screen with ubuntu options.My BIOS 4 years old (hp pavalion - but i replace the hp hardisk with windows VISTA to new empty hard disk that have on him the ubuntu.)   I get in beggening the bios screen of HP then black screen and then again bios screen of hp and again..(infinite loop).

Comment: @Yosef: try re-installing your bootloader

Comment: thanks, How can i reinstall my bootloader?i can only use ubuntu live cd

Comment: Try searching for "ubuntu reinstall bootloader from livecd", lots of promising results.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disk partitions are linear chunks of your disk. You can't have a partition that starts at the top, has a hole in it, and continues somewhere else.

---

Usual warning: messing with your partition layout is one of the faster ways to lose all your data. Make sure you have a backup of anything important, and take your time - don't rush past warnings or errors the tools report.

---

Since `sda2` is a swap device, it doesn't contain any useful information when the OS is not running; so you can just delete it.

Once that is done, you should be able to extend `sda1` to however much you want, and re-create a swap partition.

You should also consider using `lvm`. It is quite handy and will allow you to control your disk usage more finely. See [Setting Up LVM- Without A Clean Install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpLVM-WithoutACleanInstall) for example.

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 6):

Like Mat said, you can't have partitions out of non-contiguous space, so if you want to enlarge `sda1`, you need to take `sda2` out of the way.

Again, as Mat said, as `sda2` is a swap partition, there's nothing you need to keep there, so you can just get rid of it.

For short, you want/need to do as follows

1. get `sda2` out of the way
2. make `sda1` bigger
3. create another swap partition

Now, for the small print and important details

1. *Disable* the swap space before getting rid of the partition — `swapoff /dev/sda2` should do it, and after that you can get rid of `sda2` simply by removing the partition from the partition table
2. *Remove* `sda2` from the partition table using some partition table editor utility - `gparted`, `cfdisk`, `fdisk` (here, focus on picking one you feel comfortable with — after all messing with an alien tool, such as using `gparted` if you've got no clue where the options are, or `fdisk` if you don't know what are the commands, is just a shortcut to get rid of your precious data (you *can* picture Andy Serkis saying "my precious data")
3. Now you have unallocated space after `sda1` — you can now *enlarge the partition* to 90 GB. This, if I'm not mistaken, is just changing the partition table so that it lists the new, larger size for the partition. Depending on the partitioning tool, this and the next step may be bundled in the same option/feature.
4. After enlarging the partition, you can finally *extend/grow the filesystem* which lives in the partition so that it spans the full size of the partition. This requires a filesystem-aware tool. I've been able to grow ext2/ext3 partitions from `gparted`, I don't know about ext4 — if ext4 is to ext3 as ext3 is to ext2 (just additions), then I'd guess the same tool `gparted` uses for ext2/ext3 should be able to handle ext4.
5. Finally, you can recreate your swap partition. Bonus credit if you create it as `sda2` (which should happen unless you create an extended partition), as you won't have to change your configuration files to use the new swap. Use `swapon` to start using the new swap partition with no reboot.

Please note that, although all steps but 4 are (probably) possible to carry on a live system which is using the disk and has `sda1` mounted, step 4 above must be done with `sda1` *unmounted*. In the end, it's probably easier if you do all of it from a live CD — there is a [gparted livecd](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), you can try that. But any other live CD should do, as far as it has the partitioning tool, the filesystem growing tool, and is recent enough to handle your hardware (unless you're using a bleeding edge northbridge or SATA controller, or trying to partition a terabyte drive from Damn Small Linux (well, maybe it actually works, I just remember the userland tools are unable to deal with >4GB files, which is a totally different issue), you shouldn't have to worry about this).

Comment: This is correct with a couple points worth noting. After resizing the partition, a reboot will be required for the system to re-read the partition table (not required if the filesystem can be unmounted though). Also part 4 *can* be done on a live system. `resize2fs` is capable of resizing mounted filesystems.

Comment: This is just an additional hint to Comment by @Patrick in @njsg's answer. If you have gparted installed `partprobe /dev/sda` will rescan the partition table without rebooting.

Comment: please see my update